# Having trouble rotating div via css("transform":"(180deg)");

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, 3d

http://codepen.io/kaigenji/pen/peyjL

Hey everyone, I'm trying to get my .flip divs to flip through rotateY, but what I have isn't working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Would very much appreciate some help. Thanks.

JS:

```
$("#a1, #a2, #a3, #a4").hover(function(){
  $(".flip").css("background-color","yellow");
  $(".flip").css("transform":"(180deg)");
  },function(){
  $(".flip").css("background-color","#00FF00");
  $(".flip").css("transform":"");
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="tile_wrapper">

    <div id="a1" class="tile a one">
      <div class="frame">
        <div class="flip"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="a2" class="tile a two">
      <div class="frame">
        <div class="flip"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="a3" class="tile a three">
      <div class="frame">
        <div class="flip"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="a4" class="tile a four">
      <div class="frame">
        <div class="flip"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .frame, .flip {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 0;
}

#tile_wrapper {
   width: 232px;
   height: 50px;
}


.tile {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   padding: 4px;
}

.tile {
   -webkit-perspective: 100px;
   -moz-perspective: 100px;
   -o-perspective: 100px;
   perspective: 100px;
}

.flip {
   transition: background-color 0.6s ease-out;
   background-color: #00FF00;
}

.frame {
   -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transition: 0.6s;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -o-transition: 0.6s;
   -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transition: 0.6s;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: replace `:` with `,` in `.css("transform":"(180deg)")`

Comment: thanks for the correction, but the flipping part is still not functioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this JS, you are forgetting to tell it to rotateY:

```
$("#a1, #a2, #a3, #a4").hover(function(){
  $(".flip").css("background-color","yellow");
  $(".frame").css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");
  },function(){
  $(".flip").css("background-color","#00FF00");
  $(".frame").css("transform","rotateY(0)");
});
```